# SPRESENSEのAdd-onボードについて

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEのadd-onボードにある地磁気センサとジャイロセンサの使用を考えています。
それぞれのセンサは別々のadd-onボードになっており、ピン配列を見ると1つのSPRESENSEで併用できないように見受けられます。
この場合、2つのSPRESENSEを用意することになるのでしょうか。

Comment: [センサシールド SHIELD-EVK-001](https://www.rohm.co.jp/sensor-shield-support/shield) が使えるかどうか、メーカーに聞いてみるとか。あるいは覚悟して人柱となって試してみるとか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  ご提案頂いた[センサーシールドSHIELD-EVK-001](https://www.rohm.co.jp/sensor-shield-support/shield)を使用すれば、地磁気センサと
ジャイロセンサの併用は、可能そうですね。  [SPRESENSEの拡張ボード](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/specifications)に、このシールドが載せられそうなので
「メインボード + 拡張ボード + センサーシールド」の組み合わせで試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

I2CインターフェースなのでAdd-onボードをスタック構成で接続すれば併用可能です。

ロームのセンサ
https://www.rohm.co.jp/support/spresense-add-on-board
ボッシュのセンサ
https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/5258/

元々付いているコネクタを外して上下に重ねるようにロングピン等で接続し直すか、もしくは、ロームのセンサに拡張のピンソケットがあるので(https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/Arduino)、そこからVDD_3.3V, GND, SCL, SDAの４ピンをボッシュのセンサに接続することで両方のAdd-onボードが使えるようになります。

私は手っ取り早く後者の方法で試してみました。
SpresenseのWireライブラリについているI2cScannerサンプルを動かしてみると、

```
I2C Scanning...

     -0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -A -B -C -D -E -F
0- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0f
1- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1f
2- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
3- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
4- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
5- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5d -- --
6- : -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
7- : -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

the number of found I2C devices is 5.
```

合計５つの全スレーブデバイスが問題無く見えました。